# Proof that needs to be split

Tags: equations, amsmath, page-breaking, theorems

I have written a proof and for some unknown reason LaTeX positions it strangely. So it starts the proof at the bottom of the page and puts all the rest of the proof on the same page. The end of the proof is therefore on the margin.
What can I do so that there is no big blank space between "First sentence..."
and the beginning of the proof and that the proof is correctly displayed on multiple pages ?

I used:

```
\begin{proof}
 First sentence...
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
...
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{proof}
```

and I put

```
\allowdisplaybreaks
```

after

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

but it did not help.

Comment: We would need a full minimal (non-)working code to be able to see what happens.

Comment: `\raggedbottom` in the preamble might help, but may give you undesired output.

Comment: `split` cannot be broken across pages, as far as I know; only `align` or `gather`. Use `align*`: I can't see the reason for an equation number in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `split` environment cannot be broken across pages, even if `\allowdisplaybreak` is in force. This has nothing to do with being in a `proof` environment or with using `classicthesis`; it is an inherent limitation of `amsmath`.

Use `align*`, instead, as the following example shows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % for avoiding overlong pages
\usepackage{amsmath}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\section{A long align}

Some text before
\begin{align*}
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b
\end{align*}

\section{A long split}

Some text before
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
a&=b
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The terminal output is clear about what happens:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./splitsplit.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(./splitsplit.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
[2]
Overfull \vbox (170.1335pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[3] (./splitsplit.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/local/texlive/2016/te
xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2016/tex
mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2016/texm
f-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on splitsplit.pdf (3 pages, 30155 bytes).
Transcript written on splitsplit.log.
```

The relevant part is

```
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
[2]
Overfull \vbox (170.1335pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[3] (./splitsplit.aux) )
```

We have two pages for the long `align*`, but the long `split` cannot be broken, so it creates an overfull page.

Final notes. If the proof consists entirely of the  alignment, you need `\qedhere` at the end, when using `amsthm` (`ntheorem` can be coerced into adding it automatically, but it's not the way I recommend). More important, use `\allowdisplaybreaks` only in the preliminary stages and, for the final revision, add `\displaybreak` at appropriate spots: you don't want to end the proof with a single widow line, do you?

Comment: you might want to mention that, if the display is at the end of the proof, the tombstone can still split to the next page, so some attention is needed.  `\qedhere` with `amsthm`, or i think that `ntheorem` may have a different way of handling this.